# Adobe Illustrator: Prevent graphics styles from overriding stroke and fill?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a graphics style that has the following attributes:

> Stoke: None
>   Fill: None
>   3D Extrude and Bevel: Applied [*]
>   Opacity: Default

<sup>[*] Actually, this links to countless irrelevant parameters</sup>

I want to do is apply the 3D Extrude and Bevel to multiple paths at once.

By highlighting the paths and clicking on the graphics style, I achieve this effect, but the various "Stoke" and "Fill" of the selected paths is overridden by the graphics style's "no fill" and "no stroke". Basically, it 3D extrudes the paths okay, but then it goes and makes them colorless as well.

How can I disable/prevent that when I can't delete the Stroke, Fill or Opacity Graphics Styles attributes?

Answer (score 2):

Unless someone knows something I don't, a graphic style is an all or nothing affair. One of the many reasons Adobe should consider it an incomplete feature. If they would just finish the good ideas they've started ... .

The only alternative to consistently applying a style to multiple objects over time is via scripting. It's actually not that bad once you know the specific parameters, just not as slick as the click to build simplicity of graphic styles.

On an ad hoc basis, you could also change the settings of the eye dropper to grab only the attributes you're after.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two types of Graphic Styles - **Group Styles** and **Object Styles**. And no, **you can not tell the difference between the two** anywhere until they are applied. (real smart Adobe!)

As Plainclothes posted, styles are all or nothing. However, you can create a Group Style which does not alter fills and strokes and merely applies the 3D Effect.

To do this just select and object, group ti (even if it is just one object) and apply the Effect you want. Then drag the group tot he Graphic Styles Panel. When Applying the style, group the new object or objects prior to applying.

This basically created a second tier of appearance which won't alter the first tier items but merely apply the Effect to the objects as they currently appear.

Comment: Unfortunately, if you (or an unsuspecting collaborator) ever need to ungroup those items the style will simply disappear and leave you scratching your head. Another point on Adobe's anti-UX score card!

Comment: very true, plainclothes.